# How to remove yellow tracking dots from a document?

Tags: documents, watermark

Assume I have a document which I supspect to have yellow tracking dots. How can I remove them while keeping the actual information on the document? Is making a b&w copy enough? Is the copy machine adding its own tracking?

Would JPEG compression of the scanned document be sufficient to remove the dots? But would the scanner sensor leave its finger print in the scan?

OCR might be an option but only for text.
Bonus: How about removing image watermarks while keeping the foto motive?

Comment: I do not know of any ways to remove the yellow dots, but more information about them are available at http://www.seeingyellow.com. EFF has a small list of affected and non-affected printers here: https://www.eff.org/pages/list-printers-which-do-or-do-not-display-tracking-dots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a paper regarding yellow dots and also tools for their removal or retrieval.

[DEDA Tools](https://github.com/dfd-tud/deda)

[Paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=3206004.3206019&preflayout=flat)